# Golang - smb2 module + Basic understanding of Golang

Tags: go, smb

I have been trying to use the module:
https://godoc.org/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2#RemoteFile.ReadAt
In order to authenticate to my smb2 on a windows machine,
the authentication process goes well but the there aren't a lot of examples scripts out there..

**My function:**

```
func connect_client(host string, port string, share string) {
    //Checks for a connection on port

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    //smb auth
    d := &smb2.Dialer{
        Initiator: &smb2.NTLMInitiator{
            User:     "Testing",
            Password: "password123",
            Domain:   "win10",
        },
    }
    client, err := d.Dial(conn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection failed")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connection Succeeded")
    }
    defer client.Logoff()
    //escape the liternal strings
    host = `\\` + host + `\` + share
    fmt.Println(host)
    fs, err := client.Mount(host)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fs.Umount()
    fmt.Println(fs)
}
```

once i print out fs (*RemoteFileSystem) Im trying to understand what it means and how i can return it's value so I can use it in other functions except this local one where 'fs' is recognized..

Eventually what I want is to list all directories available (like smbclient) for example and check permissions for them.

From the above syntax I get an output as follows:
 &{0xc000048650 0xc0000160d8}

Can anybody explain to me what that means and how I can use this value to return it for other functions?

Thank you!

Comment: Mount() returns a pointer to a RemoteFileSystem. Have you looked at https://godoc.org/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2#RemoteFileSystem
for more information?

Comment: Since `fs` is a pointer, you can get to the actual struct with an *  ...  `fmt.Println(*fs)`

Comment: 1. You cannot use fmt.Println for debuging stuff like this as fmt.Println does to much magic and if you do not know by heart which magic it does interpreting its output is hard. Use fmt.Printf with **appropriate** verbs vor this. 2. You must learn Go and what pointers in Go are. 3. This has nothing to do with smb2, basically _any_ Go code is like this. 4. The name of the language is "Go". 5. I recommend working through the whole Tour of Go.

Comment: Thanks alot! will do

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comments what i wanted to do is make the function return a pointer value, which I did with the following:

```
func connect_client(host string, port string, share string) *smb2.RemoteFileSystem {
 (function from above)
 return fs
}
```

now i can use this pointer in other functions in order to make the other module functions work with it